# How I can integrate my media queries with java script for supporting @media Queries in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media

I wrote these media queries for re-size my browser window

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
 #wrapper {
width:621px;
padding-left: 50px;
 margin:0 auto; background:red;
}
}
 @media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:2047px) {
 #wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-left: 50px;
 width: 925px; background:yellow;
}
}
```

its working but in IE its not working then i read on Google that media query is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 or older. we can get this using java script , i am not able to write and integrate my above code with java-script. can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and lightweight solution is [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

All you have to do is include the script after your CSS, and it Just Works.

Here's a demo, check it in an older version of IE: http://scottjehl.github.com/Respond/test/test.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! That script looks rather handy.

Answer (score 1):

@jamman; check this article they use `java script` & `media query` in there example may that help you http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

in it you have to call a different css according to the `screen size` change.